# Regular expression to replace content parentheses and their contents

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am looking for a regular expression that will replace parentheses and the strings within them *if* the string anything that is not a digit.

The string can be any combination of characters including numbers, letters, spaces etc.

> For example:
>
> (3) will not be replaced
>
> (1234) will not be replaced
>
> (some letters) will be replaced
>
> (some letters, spaces - and numbers 123) will be replaced

So far I have a regex that will replace any parentheses and its content

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(.*?\\)","");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not good with the syntax of `replaceAll`, so I am just going to write the way you have written it. But I think I can help you with the regex.

Try this Regex:

```
\((?=[^)]*[a-zA-Z ])[^)]+?\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sfELt/3)

OR an even better one:

```
\((?!\d+\))[^)]+?\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8sfELt/5)

**Explanation(for 1st Regex)**

- `\(` - matches opening paranthesis
- `(?=[^)]*[a-zA-Z ])` - Positive Lookahead - checks for 0 or more of any characters which are not `)` followed by a space or a letter
- `[^)]+?` - Captures 1 or more characters which are not `)`
- `\)` - Finally matches the closing Paranthesis

**Explanation(for 2nd Regex)**

- `\(` - matches opening paranthesis
- `(?!\d+\))` - Negative Lookahead - matches only those strings which do not have ALL the characters as digits after the opening paranthesis but before the closing paranthesis appears
- `[^)]+?` - Captures 1 or more characters which are not `)`
- `\)` - Finally matches the closing Paranthesis

Now, you can try your Replace statement as:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\((?=[^)]*[a-zA-Z ])[^)]+?\)","");
```

OR

`str = str.replaceAll("\((?!\d+\))[^)]+?\)","");`